# União de vetores

Tags: c, array

Como faço para unir 2 vetores em 1 único vetor ? Sem repetir os números ?

Questão: Faça um programa que leia dois vetores de 10 elementos. Crie um vetor que seja a união entre os 2 vetores anteriores, ou seja, que contem os números dos dois vetores. Não deve conter números repetidos.

@edit: vi alguns exemplos na internet e cheguei a isso porem a ta bem errado ;-;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
int vetA[2], vetB[2], vetC[4], i,l,j;


printf ("Informe 10 valores para o VETOR A:\n");
for (i=0; i<2; i++){
scanf ("%d", &vetA);
}

printf ("Informe 10 valores para o VETOR B:\n");
for (i=0; i<2; i++){
    scanf ("%d", &vetB);
}

printf ("\nA uniao e: ");
for (i=0; i<2; i++){
    if ((vetC[0] != vetA[i]) && (vetC[1] != vetA[i]) && (vetC[2] != vetA[i]))
    printf ("%d ", vetA[i]);
}

for (i=0; i<l; i++){
    printf ("%d ",vetC);
}
for (j=0; j<2; j++){
    if ((vetC[0] != vetB[i]) && (vetC[1] != vetB[i]) && (vetC[2] != vetB[i]))
    printf ("%d ", vetB[i]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `vetC` poderia começar como tendo todos os elementos do `vetA` e tendo 20 elementos.

Depois, coloque um `for` dentro do outro para escolher quais elementos do `vetB` você coloca no `vetC`. O `for` externo percorre o `vetB` e o interno percorre o `vetA`.

Coloque uma variável dentro do `for` externo chamada `achou` e inicialize ela com 0. Se no `for` interno você descobrir que o elemento do `vetB` (do `for` externo) é igual ao elemento do `vetA` (do `for` interno), você troca o valor de `achou` para 1. Use um `if` para fazer essa verificação.

Depois do `for` interno, ainda dentro do `for` externo, use um outro `if` com a variável achou para decidir sse você coloca o elemento do `vetB` no `vetC`.

Você vai precisar também de uma variável para rastrear quantos elementos você colocou no `vetC`, uma vez que o tamanho do `vetC` é variável dependendo do número de repetições que existir.

Comment: obrigado :D vlw man

Comment: Esse algoritmo funciona bem sss `vetA` não contiver repetições. `vetB` pode ser uma bag sem problemas que esse algoritmo continua funcionando.